# playing .mov files in iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, .mov

So I am trying to play an intro scene in the format of a .mov file in my iOS (cocos2d) game.

This is my current code.

```
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DD Logo" ofType:@"mov"]];
    MPMoviePlayerController * mpc;
    mpc = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [mpc setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];
    mpc.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    mpc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    mpc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, winSize.width, winSize.height);

    [mpc setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeFill];
    [mpc setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
    [mpc setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
    [mpc setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeNone];

    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:mpc.view];

    [mpc play];
```

What happens is, the audio plays, but this is what the screen looks like.
http://gyazo.com/4f046472666bf1f58c88128f24e66229

Comment: Try this thread, does it solve your issues?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019200/how-to-rotate-an-mpmovieplayercontroller

Comment: that half worked, it still only shows the default quicktime logo, but that did fix the rotation thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out this git project,

Open source library called Cocos2D extensions that includes a class you can use to play videos in Cocos2D.

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions

if thats too old what about this

[CCVideoPlayer setDelegate: self];
[CCVideoPlayer playMovieWithFile: @"movie.m4v"];

or this...

http://pskfire.iteye.com/blog/1680123

Comment: thats a really old library that gives me a bunch of errors with compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have issues playing .mov files. For me when I change to mp4, it works. Your code looks right so maybe changing the format would help? It is possible the codec being used in the .mov is not iOS compatible.

Comment: Are you using the H.264 codec when creating the video file? Also what is the resolution?

Comment: I have no idea what that codec is. and the resolution is twice the size of the screen

Comment: I'm assuming you are on the iPad and, if so, the resolution is likely the problem. I believe the max you can play a video on iPad is 1920x1080. You can't have sizes like 2048x1536 for example. I'm not sure what the max is for iPhone if it is different but it might be the same. Try a smaller resolution like 1024x768 and see if you see the video.

Comment: Never mind I see you are on the iPhone. Try a resolution the size of the screen and see if that plays the video. Most likely your problem is either codec, resolution, or both.

Comment: So I changed the codec and resolution and got that all figured out, and the resolution is that of the iphone screen.  but now it looks like this.. http://gyazo.com/510bfe2ad272468766fdf254705f224b  Also, the second video (there are two, one follows the other), doesn't remove from the view..  The first one plays, and removes itself, then the second plays, and doesn't remove itself.. http://gyazo.com/c4074b2d48d1f61ab4ee56696d7b75bf

Comment: I fixed my first problem with `[mpc.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , 320, 480)];`   but I still don't know what to do about the second one not removing from view

Comment: Did you register for the notification for when video finish? You can add the observer for `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` and in the callback function remove the view of the video from the superview using `removeFromSuperview` then `release` the movie player.