# MPMoviePlayerController exit Fullscreen when rotating to Portrait

Tags: ios

I am trying to get the `MPMoviePlayerController` to enter fullscreen when in landscape and exit fullscreen when in portrait. ( like in the current YouTube app).

I am able to get the app to enter fullscreen mode in landscape, but I can't get it exit fullscreen when returning to portrait. I have noticed that when the `MPMoviePlayerController` is in Fullscreen mode, it is actually presented modally. So `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` will not work when `MPMoviePlayerController` is in fullscreen.

I also tried to add an observer for `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`, but it doesn't give me the result I want.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
NSURL *url;
url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:_movieUrl ofType:@"mp4"]];

moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

[self moviePlayerSetHeight:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];

[self.view addSubview: moviePlayer.view];
```

calling `[moviePlayer play]` in `viewDidAppear:`

```
-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
[self moviePlayerSetHeight:orientation];

if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
} else {
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party library? Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852872/mpmovieplayercontroller-fullscreen-quirk-in-ipad

Comment: No, not at all. I will update my post with some code.

Comment: when you will update?

Comment: you should check for the device's status bar orientation...if([[UIDevice currentDevice] statusBarOrientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait]) { then set it to no full screen }